# Maximum value has been exceed while fetching the record in front end side

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I created one Stored Proc, in that Stored Proc i set ***pagination*** value as **30**. But after executing the Stored Proc i got 2 extra value and it is showing **32** rows on one page.

> Showing 31-32 results of 30 results

where the maximum value was set as 30 rows only. How can i resolve this issue so that i can get only **30** records in front side application.

Comment: Adding some code would help!

Comment: "Pagination" sounds like Apex. Is it? If not, what "front end" are you talking about?

Comment: @Littlefoot Front End is the application where we can those value which is extracting from the Database side. In front end application like in one page we want to get 30 rows but after executing the Stored proc we are getting 32 rows while the maximum value has been set as 30.

Comment: Well, set **pagination value = 28** and hope for the best (as you still didn't share code you wrote, and people have difficulties in debugging code they can't see).

Comment: @Littlefoot in the Stored proc we are using two different `SELECT` statement while using `UNION ALL`. From the 2nd `SELECT` statement we are getting 2 records & from the 1st we are getting 30 records. So it is merging both the statement & get the result as 32 records in front end application. But in the front end application side maximum value has been set as 30 so it should not be exceeded as 30.

Comment: as requested twice before please provide code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading comments you wrote, perhaps using the union of two `SELECT` statements as an inline view and applying the pagination value to it might return the desired result. Something like this:

```
select * 
from (-- your current query
      select ... from ... --> returns 30 rows
      union all
      select ... from ... --> returns 2 rows
     )
where rownum <= pagination_value --> which = 30
```

Comment: Even i also thought like that but i used `CURSOR` here means inside the cursor we are using these 2 `SELECT` statement.

Comment: OK. What happened when you did that? ROWNUM will restrict number of rows returned ...

Comment: By default it will generate 30 records only. But for the certain time limit the value will be change like 100, 300, 500 etc. for 6 months, 1 year time limit. So we may not set the `rownum` here.